# How could my electric switch reverse the on and off positions!

Tags: electrical, switch

I have a plate with 3 switches in a row. All "up" lights are all on; all down lights are off. After changing a bulb, I noticed that one of the the three switches got reversed. It's now off, when up. It was annoying but I lived with it. Now a month later, the switch is back to normal with the other two switches, all up for on and all down for off. Any idea besides a poltergeist electrician to cause the change?

Comment: 99.9% of the time a plain single switch cannot do this unless busted in a very specific way.  Most other times it turns out to be a three way switch with the second switch hidden/forgotten about.  Before going looking for poltergeist, turn off the power for that light/switch and take a picture of the wires connected to it.

Comment: That one is on a what is called 3-way circuit. Means you can control that light from another position. Find the other switch

Comment: Do the switches in question have "on" and "off" labels on them?

Answer (score 4):

That switch is probably a three way switch which means somewhere there's another switch that controls the light and it has been operated. Is the switch a regular toggle with "on" and "off"  stamped on the toggle?

Comment: Gets even more fun when you have 3+ switches controlling something!

Answer (score 3):

### Very often, people want to control a light *from two or more different places*.

E.G. a room has 2 doors and you want to be able to control the light from either of them.  This is done through a very simple circuit:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFWwi.png]

See how that works? If the switches agree, the circuit is completed and the light lights.  *That means...* If one switch is down, the other one is down for "on" (agree) and up for "off" (disagree).

*What's news to you* is that a second switch exists. You or someone has thrown it.

Comment: This is interesting. In the UK, we call these switches [two-way switches](https://www.lightwiring.co.uk/two-way-switching-3-wire-system-new-harmonised-cable-colours/)  - is this a US/UK difference?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, it's like "range" and "hob".

Answer (score 2):

It’s pretty much impossible for a standard electric switch to “reverse itself”. With the mechanical design, it just isn’t happening.

That leaves two realistic possibilities:
(1) Are you sure this isn’t a three-way switch with another switch in the circuit? If that other switch were flipped, that would reverse the operation of the first switch.

(2) Someone removed the cover, turned the switch 180 degrees and put it back. Maybe someone in your household playing a prank?

Comment: Usually a single switch shows "on" and "off" stamped on it some place.  3-way switches do not.   This only applies to toggle style switches, not Decora style.